# exchange 2007 mail contact export / import

Tags: exchange-2007, email-server, shell, export, migration

Is there a shell command in Exchange 2007 to export the mail contacts located in
Recipient Configuration > Mail Contact.

we have recently started an AD forest migration and now it's time to do email servers.

Have looked and googled lots but always coming up short :(

Any help would be grealy appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do a:

```
get-mailcontact –resultsize unlimited | export-csv C:\contacts.csv
```

This would get all of the contacts and export them to a csv file.

Then copy the csv over and import them.  [This is a good article](http://exchangestories.blogspot.com/2008/03/importing-mail-contacts-to-exchange.html) on importing them.